# Cauchy Davenport in mod $n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, contest-math, additive-combinatorics

The Cauchy-Davenport inequality on an additive group $G$ is: For all $A,B\subseteq G$,

$$|A+B|\ge \min\{|G|,|A|+|B|-1\}$$

The Cauchy-Davenport inequality fails in mod $n$ ($n$ composite) because we can take any subgroup $A$, then $|A+A|=|A|$. However what happens if we insist $|A|$ does not divide $n$ (and possibly $|B|$ does not divide $n$ too)? Is there a better bound than the trivial $|A+B|\ge\max\{|A|,|B|\}$?

(I am aware of the results of Kneser, although these are not relevant here as $n$ can be even)

Comment: Examples: (1) Let $A$ be a subgroup minus a point. Then $|A+A| = |A|+1$. (2) Let $A$ be the union of two cosets of a subgroup $H$ and let $B$ be $H$ minus a point. Then $|A+B| = |A|$.

Comment: Also I don't understand your comment about Kneser not being relevant as $n$ can be even. I encourage you to study Kneser's theorem again, as it really tells you everything you usually want to know. I am referring to the theorem the says $|A+B| \ge |A+H| + |B+H| - |H|$ where $H$ is the stabilizer of $A+B$.

Comment: A theorem of Chowla states that in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ the Cauchy-Davenport inequality holds, with just the extra condition the $0\in B$ and all other elements in $B$ are invertible.

Comment: There's also the Kemperman structure theorem, which classifies all pairs $A$, $B$ in arbitrary abelian groups satisfying $|A+B| < |A| + |B|$; Lev [ZBL0956.11008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0956.11008) and Gynkiewicz  [ZBL1116.11081](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1116.11081) give detailed developments.

Grynkiewicz [ZBL1213.11179](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1213.11179) classified the pairs satisfying $|A+B| = |A| + |B|$ in arbitrary abelian groups.